# How to stop zsh printing Ruby version on every command?

Tags: ruby, homebrew, zsh, rbenv, zshrc

Since I have installed rbenv using homebrew on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2, the Terminal application that is configured to use zsh keeps printing Ruby version currently selected by rbenv on every executed command in the right side of every line containing this command. Why is that happening and is there any way to stop it? I really don't need that information every time I execute any command. I could get that information just by executing ruby -v.

Here are some examples:

```
[~]$ ls                                                                 rbenv:2.4.2  
[~]$ pwd                                                                rbenv:2.4.2  
[~]$ ifconfig                                                           rbenv:2.4.2
```

Comment: Might be added by your prompt theme. What does your `RPROMPT` says ?

Comment: $PROMPT variable is empty.

Comment: I was asking about `RPROMPT`, Which corresponds to the right section of the prompt. `PROMPT` sets the left section of the prompt. Here `ruby` version was shown own right side, so `RPROMPT` .

Comment: I don't have any settings regarding RPROMPT in my .zshrc file. Neither echoing $RPROMPT variable does return any value.

Comment: Do you use .oh-my-zsh?

Comment: Yes, I use .oh-my-zsh.